# Problems with Global Variable

Tags: python, global

I have the following function definition:

```
def rcsplit(arr):
    if np.all(arr==0): return []    # if all zeros return
    global res
    arr = delrc(arr)        # delete leading/trailing rows/cols with all zeros
    indr = np.where(np.all(arr==0,axis=1))[0]
    indc = np.where(np.all(arr==0,axis=0))[0]
    if not indr and not indc:   # If no further split possible return
        res.append(arr)
        return
    arr=np.delete(arr,indr,axis=0)  #delete empty rows in between non empty rows
    arr=np.delete(arr,indc,axis=1)  #delete empty cols in between non empty cols
    arr=np.split(arr,indc,axis=1)   # split on empty (all zeros) cols
    arr2=[]
    for i in arr:
        z=delrc(i)      
        arr2.extend(np.split(z,indr,axis=0))   # split on empty (all zeros) rows
    for i in arr2:
        rcsplit(np.array(i))
```

The problem is I receive the following error:

```
NameError: global name 'res' is not defined
```

But this exact code works on other consoles. Is it my Python 2.7?

Comment: when do you recieve that error - what is the rest of your code - is there a smaller but complete code segment thatgenerates that error.

Comment: Why are you trying to use (and declaring) a global variable inside a function?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that I simply had to define res = [] in order for it to work. Would there be a way I don't have to use a global variable in this recursion?

Comment: A way to not use a global variable would be to add a `res` function argument with a default value of `None`, then in the function check to see if that's its value and initialize it to `[]` if so. When the function calls itself recursively, pass the current value of `res` in the call (to override the default value of `None`).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the global variable `res` is not defined before the function, maybe it is defined in the other console.